# Method get_raw on pygame.mixer.Sound doesn't exists

Tags: python, pygame

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Sound' object has no attribute 'get_raw'
```

While trying to use get_raw() on a Sound object.

If I type:

```
dir(pygame.mixer.Sound)
```

Returns:

```
['__class__','__delattr__','__doc__','__format__','__getattribute__','__hash__','__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__','__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'fadeout', 'get_buffer', 'get_length', 'get_num_channels', 'get_volume', 'play', 'set_volume', 'stop']
```

I have no clue how to solve this.

Comment: What version of PyGame do you have? As the docs note, [`get_raw`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_raw) is new in 1.9.2.

Comment: Also, if you do have 1.9.2, please let us know the versions of SDL, SDL_mixer, and Python you're using, and how you installed them (and PyGame), and what platform you're on.

Comment: I'm using it over windows. I updated pygame to 1.9.2a0 and still can't use get_raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that you installed 1.9.1 or earlier of PyGame, since most of [the pre-built binaries](http://pygame.org/download.shtml) are 1.9.1 or earlier.

And if you look at the docs for [`get_raw`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_raw), it clearly says:

> New in pygame 1.9.2.

If you want to use 1.9.2-only features, you obviously need to install 1.9.2. Which means you can't use the official pre-built binaries.

There are some platforms that have their own binaries (maybe in RPM or DEB packages) or unofficial binaries (like Christoph Gohlke's archive for Windows).

Or you can always build and install PyGame yourself. The [install docs](http://www.pygame.org/install.html) appear to be broken at the moment, but the [compilation docs](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation) cover all the tricky parts. And really, it's not that tricky; once you install all the prereqs, the usual `[sudo] python setup.py install`—or, better, `[sudo] pip install .`—should just work. (If you're lucky, `pip install pygame` may even work, but only if 1.9.2 has actually been released.)

Using a version called 1.9.2a0, which sounds like a pre-alpha for 1.9.2. doesn't guarantee that you're going to get all 1.9.2 features. If there is no later version released yet… well then, you can't use new features before they're released, unless you want to use an as-yet-unreleased development build. (Note that they have automated [nightly development builds](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/wiki/VersionControl) for common Windows and Mac targets, so if you happen to match one of those targets, you may be in luck. Then again, those build are often broken for months at a time, so you may have to build it yourself.)

So, those are your choices: wait for 1.9.2 to get an official binary release, use a dev build, or stop trying to use a feature that isn't in the latest release yet.

Comment: I'm on windows and updated using easy_install. Yet I still can't use get_raw.